# How to create config maps for binary files?

Tags: kubernetes, configmap

How do I create configmap yaml for descriptor files? I understand that protobuf descriptor file is a binary however is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `binaryData` in yaml file.

Example :

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: example-config
  namespace: default
binaryData:
  bar: L3Jvb3QvMTAw
```